# How many Python versions shoud be installed simultaneously?

Tags: python

I've been trying to install PyQt4 on my Mac and I think I have successfully done that, but python can't find it and I don't know how to get them to 'talk' to each other. I have looked into `/usr/local/bin` and have found this:

```
python
python-config
python2
python2-config
python2.7
python2.7-config
python3
python3-32
python3-config
python3.5
python3.5-32
python3.5-config
python3.5m
python3.5m-config
python3.6
python3.6-32
python3.6-config
python3.6m
python3.6m-config
pythonw
pythonw2
pythonw2.7
pyuic4
pyuic5
pyvenv
pyvenv-3.5
pyvenv-3.6
```

It seems to me that these are quite a lot of different versions of python of which I surely don't need every single one. I know that some version of python2 comes preinstalled with Macintosh, and I need at least one of the python3 versions, because I'm trying to write a simple app with a few friends who all use python3, so it would make sense for me to also use that.

My question is: Can I safely throw away some of these documents? If yes, which ones are needed by my OS and can not be moved to trash? And lastly, am I right to believe that this might be a reason why PyQt4 can't be found if I'm trying to run the app I'm writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it comes down to your environment variables. This is the path that your OS uses to find the right version of python for a task. It is hard to say what you can delete and what you can't without knowing which of your programs are pointing at a specific library.

That being said, PyQT is probably not working because it is installing for a different environment variable than the one you are using for you script. Check your IDE for the path that it is using. I know in PyCharm this is under `settings` and `project interpreter`. If you install the module through pycharm it will automatically get placed in the interpreter that PyCharm is using.

At the bottom of your list you have ones that look like `pyvenv` These are virtual environments. Think of them as self contained sandboxes where you can work. All of the libraries and dependencies are local only to those. I imagine those are from your previous projects.

The short answer is that you dont have to delete any of them but you do need to make sure that you are working in the correct interpreter. If you are not using PyCharm already I recommend it as it makes this stuff easy for newbs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
I am already using PyCharm, but when I try to install PyQt4 from the project interpreter, I get this:

      ´Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt4 (from versions: )
      No matching distribution found for PyQt4`

And sorry for the dumb question, but how can I get code to be displayed as such in comments?

Comment: use the back tick symbol to display code in comments. This is the symbol above your tab key on the same key as the `tilde`.    Are you able to install other packages in pycharm?

Comment: @Joe (On a US keyboard), UK keyboards its by left shift

Comment: @Joe
Yes, I can install other packages, but for PyQt4 I get the error.

Comment: Did you try installing it with pip from the command line.  Navigate to the folder with pip in your cmd window and try `pip install bs4` or `pip3 install bs4`

Comment: also this [link](http://thyagjs.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-install-beautiful-soup-or-bs4-on.html) looks promising as a tutorial. PyCharm sometimes cannot find the right package. Manually installing it usually does the trick

Comment: I did manage to install PyQt4 now via PyCharm. Unfortunately, I don't know what exactly caused PyCharm to now be able to install it, since the first few times I tried it didn't work. That probably makes this thread pretty useless for people in the future with the same problem... Still, thank you very much for taking the time to help me :)